# JS: Timer function with dynamic interval getting "off" by one second(out of sync)?

Tags: javascript, date, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a simple progressive timer function with a dynamic interval.

## The Goal:

To have this function to run every XX:00:00 or XX:30:00 in as few executions as possible. It starts of running every second, then every 5 seconds, 10, 30 etc until it gets to every 30 minutes on  user's :30 min mark or new hour mark.
(I am eventually going to use this in an AngularJS-powered schedule app to update what events are currently happening every half-hour.)

---

## The Problem:

This timer works just fine but occasionally it gets 1 second off and keeps resetting.

### Examples:

#### Running as intended:

```
Tick 29: 22
Running every 1 second
Tick 29: 23
Running every 1 second
Tick 29: 24
Running every 1 second
Tick 29: 25
Running every 5 seconds
Tick 29: 30
Running every 30 seconds
Tick 30: 0
Running every 30 minutes
Tick 0: 0
Running every 30 minutes
```

#### Insanity (Randomly getting off by a second)

```
Running every 1 second
Tick 30: 53
Running every 1 second
Tick 30: 55
Running every 5 seconds
Tick 31: 1
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 3
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 5
Running every 5 seconds
Tick 31: 11
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 13
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 15
Running every 5 seconds
Tick 31: 21
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 22
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 24
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 26
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 28
Running every 1 second
Tick 31: 30
Running every 30 seconds
```

---

## My Question:

Why? Why does it seem to randomly get off by one second and how can I prevent this? Is there a better way to achieve this?  I suspect it may have something to do with `Date().getSeconds()`

---

## Code:

On CodePen: http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/RKRVXe

```js
/* Description: A dynamic timer function to run every XX:00:00 or XX:30:00 in as few executions as possible */
var one_sec   = 1000; // One second is 1,000 milliseconds
var one_min   = one_sec * 60; // Times 60 is a minute
var intervalms = one_sec;  // This is how often we'll run the function | Every 1s at first

//Some variables so we can output it to the screen instead of console
var messageHolder = document.getElementById("messageHolder");
var m             = one_sec; // MSG: What unit of time we're measuring in
var mString       = " second"; // MSG: String value of time measument

function tick() {
 clearInterval(interval); //Clear the timer so we can start with new dynamic value.
  var secs = new Date().getSeconds(); //get the second mark of the current time
    var mins = new Date().getMinutes(); //get the minute mark of the current time
     if (secs == "00"){ // If the value of secs is currently 0 (new minute XX:XX:00)
            intervalms = one_min;  // Set the interval every minute
            m          = one_min;
            mString = " minute"
         // Internal if: New minute AND
            // Minute mark is at XX:00:00 OR XX:30:00
               if (mins == "00" || mins == "30") {intervalms = 30 * one_min; mString =" minutes"; } //set every half-hour
              //Otherwise: if Minute mark is divisible by 10 (like 'XX:10:00', 'XX:20:00', etc)
          else if (mins % 10 == 0)  {intervalms = 10 * one_min; mString =" minutes";} //set every 10 minutes
            //Otherwise: if Minute mark is divisible by 5 (like 'XX:05:00', 'XX:10:00', etc)
          else if (mins % 5  == 0)  {intervalms =  5 * one_min; mString =" minutes";} //set every 5 minutes
         } // END if (new minute XX:XX:00)
    // Original if: Not a new minute     
     //Otherwise: if the value of secs is currently 30 (new minute XX:XX:30)
   else if (secs      == "30") {intervalms = 30 * one_sec; mString = " seconds";} //set every 30 seconds
     //Otherwise: if second mark is divisible by 10 (like 'XX:10:00', 'XX:20:00', etc)
   else if (secs % 10 ==   0 ) {intervalms = 10 * one_sec; mString = " seconds";} //set every 10 seconds
     //Otherwise: if second mark is divisible by 5 (like 'XX:05:00', 'XX:10:00', etc)
    else if (secs % 5  ==   0 ) {intervalms =  5 * one_sec; mString = " seconds";} //set every 5 seconds
  // if none of the above things are true `intervalms` is never reassigned and the function runs every second
  
    // EDIT: Sanity Check: Apparently it can get off so reset to 1s if needed
    else {intervalms = one_sec; mString = " second"; m = one_sec;}
    // Logging to console
    console.log('Tick ' + mins + ': ' + secs); //Output stuff to the console so we can see it
    console.log('Running every ' + (intervalms/m) + mString);
  
    // Appending content in the html
    msg = document.createElement("div");
    msg.innerHTML = 'Tick ' + mins + ': ' + secs +'<br>';
    msg.innerHTML += 'Running every ' + (intervalms/m) + mString;
    messageHolder.appendChild(msg);
  
    interval = setInterval(tick, intervalms);
}
var interval = setInterval(tick, intervalms);
```

```html
<h1>A simple progrssive timer</h1>
<p>A dynamic timer function to run every XX:00:00 or XX:30:00 in as few executions as possible. </p>
<p>This timer can apparently get off at random?</p>
<div id="messageHolder"> </div>
```

Comment: `setInterval` and `setTimer` only guarantee that they'll run in at least that time, not that the timer will be exact. The function is added to the event queue at the time specified, but if the browser is busy or there are other events ahead of it, it won't run immediately.

Comment: Isnt getMinutes a number?

Comment: The usual fix is to use sequential calls to *setTimeout* and on each call, work out the ms to the next time it should run, e.g. for just after the next full second the delay might be `1020 - (date.now() % 1000)`.

Comment: Using sequential *setInterval* calls, then clearing the interval as the first statement in the function means you are trying to use it like *setTimeout*. So just use *setTimeout*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Done, http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/XpKYKW thank you! I've added variables to figure out the delay between cycles.  It seems to be working okay but it's kind of wonky.  I'd really like to try and use your way with the modulo to get even times (ms) but I can't figure it out just yet.  I'll keep pondering... thank you!

Comment: @RobG, Nevermind, my delay tracking works horribly upon further testing! Aaaah D:

Comment: @StephanieQ—yes, did some testing myself and even over a 1 minute period, *setTimeout* drifts by more than 7 seconds (i.e. a delay of 60,000 ms can take more than 67,000ms to run). So it seems the timer should run much more frequently, but still just do updates when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *setTimeout* and *setInterval* drift a lot over periods of more than a few seconds, so it's likely best to run a timer more frequently and then call the function only when necessary.

The following calculates the required delay using the general equation:

delay to next run = length of period - time since end of last period + buffer

The following calculates the time to the next even period and accommodates timezone offsets which might have 15 or 30 minute components (all values are milliseconds):

```
var now = new Date();
var lengthOfPeriod = 30 * 60 * 1000; // or just 1.8e6
var timeSinceEndOfLast = (now.getMinutes() % 30) * 6e4 +
                          now.getSeconds() * 1000 +
                          now.getMilliseconds();
```

Another approach is to use Date.now and adjust the value by the local timezone offset:

```
var now = new Date();
var lengthOfPeriod = 30 * 60 * 1000; // or just 1.8e6
var timeSinceEndOfLast = (Date.now() - now.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4) % lengthOfPeriod;
```

I've also added a small buffer to ensure it runs just after the period. This should be able to be adapted to any even time period, e.g minute, 5 minute, 30 minute, 2 hours, whatever.

```js
function showTime() {
  var clock = document.querySelectorAll('.clock');
  var now = new Date();
  clock[0].textContent = now.getHours();
  clock[1].textContent = ('0' + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
  clock[2].textContent = ('0' + now.getSeconds()).slice(-2);
}

/* Run provided function on each even multiple of period
** Function runs 90% of the way to the next period, or on period
** if delay is less than 1 second (1000 ms);
** @param {Function} fn - function to run
** @param {number} period - even period in ms (e.g. 60000 for one minute)
** @param {boolean} hold - don't run the first call (default is false)
*/
function doUpdate(fn, period, hold) {
  var buffer = 20;
  if (!hold) fn();
  hold = false;
  var now = new Date();
  var delayToNext = period - ((Date.now() - now.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4) % period);
  if (delayToNext > 1000) {
    delayToNext *= .9;
    hold = true;
  }
  setTimeout(function(){doUpdate(fn, period, hold)}, delayToNext + buffer);
}

window.onload = function() {
  doUpdate(showTime, 60000); // run each minute
}
```

```css
.clock {
  width: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>Hr<th>Min<th>Sec
  <tr>
    <td class="clock">
    <td class="clock">
    <td class="clock">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the modulo suggestion in here http://codepen.io/StuffieStephie/pen/XpKYKW and it hasn't gotten off yet, so hurray. Thank you for following up.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a recommendation. Your if else stuff is really long. May do this:

```
function ticker(times,callback,i=0){
  setTimeout(function(){
    callback();
    ticker(times,callback,i+1);
  },times[i]);
 }
```

Use like this:

```
ticker([5,10,20,30,3000],function(){
  alert(new Date.getMinutes());
});
```

It will execute the code after 5,10... Seconds

Or if you wanna execute al half hour:

```
function allhalfhour(func){
   var time=30-(new Date().getMinutes()%30);//time missing to a multiple of a half hour (30 or 60);
   setTimeout(function(){
     func();
     setInterval(func,60*30);
   },60*time);
 }
```

Use like this:

```
allhalfour(function(){
 alert(new Date.getMinutes());
});
```

Comment: The goal is not to have it simply run every 30 minutes. The goal is to run every 30 minutes once we've established the user's time something like `1:00` or  `1:30`.  I appreciate the input though.